# iOS7 Safari address bar overlaps page content for about 10 px in iPad Simulator

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

I am optimizing a site for tablets and seeing the issue with Safari on iPad. When I change simulator orientation from Portrait to Landscape, I see that top horizontal panel with the address bar goes above 10 px overlapping page content and hiding some part of it.

How can I make top page side to be just side by side with the bottom side of the address bar?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in iOS 7. There's not really a good solution. You'll have to detect that the user is running ios 7 and style the page appropriately.

see: [Scrolling problems on a web page with fixed header and footer in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110052/scrolling-problems-on-a-web-page-with-fixed-header-and-footer-in-ios7)