# height of html in IOS web app

Tags: ios, html, css, cordova

I have designed an web app well working on desktop browser and on ipad safari.

However, when I install it as an hybrid app with `cordova 3.3.0`, the height is not proper.

My footer is around 40 to 60 px upper the bottom although I have a `position: fixed` and `bottom:0` rule in my css file.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the following question: [Div element wont stay at bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977540/div-element-wont-stay-at-the-bottom-when-ios-7-virtual-keyboard-is-present)
It could have something to with the webview not scaling properly. Hope this helps.

Comment: Doing this makes the height of the page too long and I can srcoll my page even if there is no content. I have no problem with keyboard

Comment: Are you using some kind of library like JQuery Mobile or Sencha Touch?

Comment: Im using jquery (not mobile) and dojo