# Retaining page layout when on-screen keyboard appears (iOS/phonegap)

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, single-page-application

I am creating a single page non-native iOS application using cordova and angularJS. Whenever the onscreen iPad keyboard appears, the div elements are moved up and squashed together to compensate for the smaller viewing screen size.

How would I go about making all the div elements stay in place when the keyboard pops up, just cutting out the bottom part of the screen which the keyboard takes up, without rearranging all the elements?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this to your config.xml:

```
<preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="false" />
```

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977540/div-element-wont-stay-at-the-bottom-when-ios-7-virtual-keyboard-is-present/18991076#18991076) It is a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks, this didn't seem to work but following the link you sent me this did the job `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />`

Comment: Thanks @FootsieNG - I'm doing a native AngularJS app and every time a keyboard popped up in a modal, the screen width would go crazy...you solved it for me...+1!